# Python Multiprocessing - Writing to a JSON file

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, multiprocessing, pool

I have a requirement where I am reading Order Dictionary from an Rest-API as given below:-

```
OrderedDict([('_bkt', 'ii~1809~C76785F7-95DF-4D1D-A5E7-A2202947734C'), ('_cd', '1809:718727061')])
OrderedDict([('_bkt', 'ii~1809~C76785F7-95DF-4D1D-A5E7-A2202947735C'), ('_cd', '1809:718727063')])
OrderedDict([('_bkt', 'ii~1809~C76785F7-95DF-4D1D-A5E7-A2202947736C'), ('_cd', '1809:718727065')])
OrderedDict([('_bkt', 'ii~1809~C76785F7-95DF-4D1D-A5E7-A2202947737C'), ('_cd', '1809:718727067')])
```

My requirement is to read Ordered Dictionary and write data in JSON format in Multiprocessing to a JSON file. But my code is not working properly, it is not writing data in JSON format to my target file. Please suggest.

Code is given below:-

```
from multiprocessing import Pool
from collections import OrderedDict
import simplejson as json

rr = OrderedDict([('_bkt', 'ii~1809~C76785F7-95DF-4D1D-A5E7-A2202947734C'), ('_cd', '1809:718727061')])

f = open('iitp222.json', "a")

def write_data(args):
    f.write(args + '\n')

###Get the results and display them using the ResultsReader.
if __name__ == "__main__":
    for result in rr:
            print result
            p = Pool()
            result = p.map(write_data, json.dumps(result))
            p.close()
            p.join()
    f.close()
```

Comment: the code doesn't make much sense, for each item in the dictionary you are creating a new pool and trying to incorporate multiprocessing for a _single_ item. also iterating over a dictionary will only yield you keys, not values

Comment: This code is just an example. As i said initially that i am pulling data from Rest-API and data which i receive is Ordered Dictionary. My requirement is to read from Rest-API and write it to a JSON file in multiprocessing. As currently i am writing data on single core then processing time is quite high. My requirement is to shorten complete reading and writing part.

Comment: it sounds like you need to use multi-threading or async for making multiple requests at a time, since that is I/O bound code and then use multiprocessing for doing multiple writes at once since writing to disk is CPU bound.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am able to solve my problem through following code

```
#------------Import Lib-----------------------#
import splunklib.results as results
from collections import OrderedDict
import splunklib.client  as client
import simplejson as json, sys
from datetime import datetime
import multiprocessing as mp

fn=sys.argv[1]
HOST = "restapi.xxxx.com"
PORT = 443

#----Capturing Current Hour & Min--------------#
Cur_min1 = datetime.now().strftime('%M')
Cur_min = int(Cur_min1)/2

#----Evaluating time to flip different users --- #
if int(Cur_min) % 4 == 0:
        USERNAME = "xxxxxx"
        PASSWORD = "yyyyyy"
elif int(Cur_min) % 4 == 1:
        USERNAME = "xxxxxx"
        PASSWORD = "yyyyyy"
elif int(Cur_min) % 4 == 2:
        USERNAME = "kuuuu1"
        PASSWORD = "yyyyyy"
else:
        USERNAME = "xxxx"
        PASSWORD = "yyyyyy"

# Create a Service instance and log in
try:
    service = client.connect(
        host=HOST,
        port=PORT,
        username=USERNAME,
        password=PASSWORD)
    rr = results.ResultsReader(service.jobs.export("search index=xxx host=yyyyyy* sourcetype=xxxx splunk_server=idx* earliest=-2m@m"))
    f1=open(fn, 'w')
    f1.close()
except:
    os.system("python /home/xxx/MS_TeamsNotification.py 'Unable to connect Splunk Rest-API'")
    exit()

###Get the results and display them using the ResultsReader.

def worker(arg, q):
    res = json.dumps(arg)
    q.put(res)
    return res

def listener(q):
    '''listens for messages on the q, writes to file. '''
    with open(fn, 'w') as f:
        while 1:
            m = q.get()
            if m == 'kill':
                break
            f.write(str(m) + '\n')
            f.flush()

def main():
    #must use Manager queue here, or will not work
    manager = mp.Manager()
    q = manager.Queue()
    pool = mp.Pool(mp.cpu_count() + 2)

    #put listener to work first
    watcher = pool.apply_async(listener, (q,))

    #fire off workers
    jobs = []
    for result in rr:
        if isinstance(result, dict):
            job = pool.apply_async(worker, (result, q))
            jobs.append(job)
    assert rr.is_preview == False

    # collect results from the workers through the pool result queue
    for job in jobs:
        job.get()

    #now we are done, kill the listener
    q.put('kill')
    pool.close()
    pool.join()

if __name__ == "__main__":
   main()
```